# Inserting an image into Oracle this way?

Tags: sql, vb.net, image, oracle

Below is just an example from some of my code, all this works fine.  However I recently had to have a column added to this table for a BLOB image.  This particular form is setup so the user can browse and select an image however I am not sure how to incorporate inserting that image now.  I've also not had to previously insert an image into sql/oracle before so learning this part as I go.

```
STSQL = "insert into mpcs.shop_inv_history"
        STSQL = STSQL & " ("
        STSQL = STSQL & "SI_KEY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "DATE_TIME,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "ACTION,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "EMPL_ID,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "QUANTITY,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "COMMENTS"
        STSQL = STSQL & ") values ("
        STSQL = STSQL & varSi & ","
        STSQL = STSQL & "to_date(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'),"
        STSQL = STSQL & "0,"
        STSQL = STSQL & "'" & cboEmployee.Text & "',"
        If chkConsumable.Checked Then
            STSQL = STSQL & txtQuan.Text & ","
        Else
            STSQL = STSQL & "1,"
        End If
        STSQL = STSQL & "'ADDED NEW ITEM'"
        STSQL = STSQL & ")"

        MPCS_UPDATE_SQL(UCase(STSQL))
        rsMPCS.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("ADDED")
```

MPCS_UPDATE_SQL within Modmodule  (this all was what was done before I took over, I can only get things working with what I have.  I don't have the permission to rewrite everything right now).

```
Public Sub MPCS_UPDATE_SQL(ByVal strSQL As String)
    Dim cmdMPCS As OleDbCommand
    Try

        If OPEN_CONNECTIONS() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to database.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            cmdMPCS = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conMPCS)
            cmdMPCS.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Err.Clear()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: First off, you **really** need to parameterize your statement, and not use literal string values.  Since we do not see what data type the table column for your image is, nor do we know what MPCS_UPDATE_SQL does,  no easy way to provide an answer.

Comment: Provided more information to post.

Comment: What is the data type in the table for your image????

Comment: In the update yesterday I stated it is a BLOB.

Comment: Well, then if you cannot modify your procedure, you are out of luck, I think.  You would need to parameterize the sql ,and do some more work.  Look at - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13365/Insert-retrieve-an-image-into-from-a-blob-field-in